# Selecting only rows corresponding to Thursday in a column of dates

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I've the following dates in a column and I'd like to select only the rows corresponding to Thursday in Google Sheets. Could you tell me how to get this result, please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a formula: `=filter(A2:A,weekday(A2:A)=5))`

Using the filter option in the taskbar: Use 'filter by condition'/'custom formula is' and set the formula to `=weekday(A2:A)=5`

Comment: Hello @TheGodofBiscuits could you tell me where is 'filter by condition'/'custom formula is' please? In the taskbar I have: File, Edit, View, Insert, Format, Data, Tools, Extensions, Help. I forgot to tell you that I need each Thursday in a single cell.

Comment: After you have selected the range to be filtered (remember to include a header row!) and clicked on the filter icon in the task bar to apply a filter, click on the 'downward triangle' in the cell at the top of the range.

Comment: Comments are transient.   If you think someone else might benefit from the additional info you should consider adding it to the answer